# Flutter onPressed pass function

Tags: flutter

I have a problem with the onPressed I am trying to pass function x but Android Studio is giving me an error that it require void function on line 19
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNs4W.png)

I tried to fix the error but I couldn't fix it although it works fine when bypass function as anonymous function [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pGjK.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

> const

behind constructor and use method like this

```
onPress:(){
     x();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that the `Function x` can return a dynamic output and takes dynamic parameters. Instead of having `final Function x;`, use `final void Function() x;`.
Or if the function `x` is not the same type as `void Function()`, just do

```
onPressed: () {
     x();
    }
```

Comment: You copy my answer and reach the check , this is not nice ...

Comment: Oof dude. There were no answers when I clicked on this question. And I explained more properly so that the original author could understand, since he's new to stackoverflow.
It's not my problem he selected mine instead of yours.